# WPF Pack Uri for refrencing file in user directory

Tags: .net, wpf, pack-uri

How can we use wpf pack uri to reference a file located in user directory. My application creates a folder in user directory and files are downloaded there from internet, which needed to be loaded in wpf through pack uri.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pack uri's only reference files relative to assemblies or the site of origin.  Please see:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa970069.aspx

To reference a file in a user directory you can use a uri something like this:
file:///C:/Users/User3/Pictures/screen.jpg